# Constructing JSON object from text file in Spring Project

Tags: java, json, spring

I am wondering if there is a way to read a text file from resources folder inside a spring project and convert the text file contents to Java.

I have tried reading the file and converting the object to a JSONobject using the code below, but no luck.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = ResourceLoader.class.getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("input.txt").getFile());

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser("input.txt");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google json works .

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
InputStream pdInputStream = 
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.json");
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(pdInputStream);
JSONObject a = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
```

With following maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```